# Effective dating a Custom Object field in Salesforce

Tags: custom-object

Suppose the value of the field changes with dates, or if I want to track the value of a field an year ago (archiving the previous values), what is the best way to implement it?. Something similar to [effective dating in PeopleSoft](https://ashrivastav.wordpress.com/about/step-by-step-learning-guide-to-peoplesoft/concept-of-dates-in-peoplesoft/)

Comment: Just wondering if you implemented a solution for this. I'm running into the same requirement.

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1 Analytic Snapshots**

One solution is to use Analytic Snapshots. You can read about it in detail in SFDC Help but the general solution is:

1. Create a report that captures the fields you are interested in comparing over time
2. Create a custom object that has custom fields corresponding to each of the report columns
3. Create an Analytic Snapshot that maps the fields from the report to the custom object fields
4. Schedule the Analytic Snapshot (weekly, monthly, ..)
5. Create reports on the custom object in #2 grouped by snapshot date

**Option 2 Track History on field(s)**

Enable field history tracking for the object in question; then enable the field(s) you want to track.

1. Tracking starts with the next insert/update event
2. There are OOB reports that can be used to locate all changes to a specific field by whom by date with new/old values
3. Some limitations in the field history report with fields such as multi-select picklists and long text fields won't have old/new values

Comment: Field history tracking is somewhat useful if you want a snapshot of a row (in the past). But what if one wants to set the value of a field for future dates? (Suppose if I want to change discount rates for the next month)

Comment: change value for future dates ? Can you update the question with an example pf what you are looking for?

Comment: Ah, I may have misunderstood your requirement - you are looking for something like SFDC dated exchange rates.  This will require a custom solution